# Solve the equation with trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{2\cos x}{(1+\cos2x)}=\frac{(1-\cos2x)}{\sin2x}$$
Here's what i did
$$\frac{2\cos x}{ (1+\cos^2x-\sin^2x)}=\frac{1-(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)}{2\sin x \cos x}$$
$$\frac{2\cos x}{2\cos^2x}= \frac{(\sin^2x+\sin^2x)}{2\sin x\cos x}.$$ How do i continue?

Comment: just cancel cos on the left fraction and sin on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2\cos x/(1+\cos 2x)=(1-\cos 2x)/\sin 2x$$
$$2\cos x/(1+\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))=(1-(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)))/(2\sin(x)\cos(x))$$
$$2\cos x/(2\cos^2(x))=(2\sin^2(x))/(2\sin(x)\cos(x))$$
$$1/\cos(x) = \sin(x)/\cos(x)$$
$$1 = \sin(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using:

$$
\cos^{2} (x) = \frac{ 1+\cos(2x)}{2}
$$

$$
\sin^{2} (x) = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}
$$